# Angular 4 case insensitive search result with pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I am creating a search pipe in angular4 which filter company name from Json Data. The search filter is working but is case sensitive, how I can I ignore case sensitivity from my search filter. I am putting only the code which is related to the subject.

My Pipe code -

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { JobsService } from '../services/jobs.service';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
    pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: any[], term): any {
    console.log('term', term);

    return term 
        ? items.filter(item => item.company.indexOf(term) != -1)
        : items;
    }
}
```

Search Box -

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" name="term">
```

Data -

```
<div *ngFor="let joblist of jobList | filter: term">
    {{joblist.company}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `String.protoype.search()` method instead of the `indexOf()` method for checking against a case insensitive regular expression.

So your `return` statement could look like this:

```
return term 
 ? items.filter(item => item.company.search(new RegExp(term, 'i')) !== -1)
 : items;
```

If you have special characters like `\` in your `terms` variable, then you need to account for that as well in your filter. The above method should work for a normal alphanumeric `terms` variable.

The `i` in `new RegExp(term, 'i')` accounts for case-insensitive `terms` pattern.

The above code will let in any `company` values which has the `term` anywhere in it. If you want a more stricter check, you can replace the `RegExp` constructor with this: `new RegExp('^' + terms + '$', 'i')` in the above code snippet. These characters, `^` & `$` specify the 'start' and 'end' of a regex pattern respectively.

More on [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) and [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Answer (score 1):

You should filter term value as:

```
...term.toLowerCase().company...
```

Comment: Hi, but it is only filtering lowercase only, for e.g if the json value says 'company1' it filters with term - company1 and not Company1 or COmpany1, and etc, I want to make it case insensitive